# Ingress-nginx and AWS NLB - cant access service behind

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, ingress-nginx, aws-nlb

I have an AWS EKS Cluster (ver. 1.24)
I use ingress-nginx helm chart (ver. 4.7.1):

```
dependencies:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    version: 4.7.1
    repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
    condition: ingress-nginx.enabled
    alias: ingress-public
```

Values for it:

```
ingress-public:
  enabled: true
  controller:
    publishService:
      enabled: true
    kind: DaemonSet
    ingressClass: nginx-public
    ingressClassResource:
      name: nginx-public
      enabled: true
      default: false
      controllerValue: "k8s.io/ingress-nginx-public"
    service:
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "Subnet_EKS_1, Subnet_EKS_2"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
      external:
        enabled: true
      externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    config:
      allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
      enable-real-ip: "true"
      proxy-body-size: 100M
      use-proxy-protocol: "true"
      use-forwarded-headers: "true"
```

MY PROBLEM IS:

If i apply this setup i see that Network loadbalancer (internet-facing) is created and my nodes attached to it via target groups with healthy status. I got DNS name for this load balancer, but **i cant connect to it** (even using this dns, to get 404, or using `nc -v lb_dnsname 443`). If i deploy simple nginxdemos/hello (deployment, service, ingress with hostname) i cant connect to it too, even i see that loadbalancerts dns name is attached. Security group for eks cluster have rules to access target group ports from 0.0.0.0/0 (created automatically). Route table for subnets contains 0.0.0.0/0 as destination and my NAT gateway as target, also VPC subnet as destination and local as target.

Please, point me what i'm doing wrong? (Yes, i know that i can use AWS Load Balancer Controller, but i want use in-tree.)

Comment: It looks like you've likely put your load balancer in a private subnet. NLB should go into a public subnet if you want it to be internet accessible.